# iPhone UUID change when App Updated?

Tags: ios, iphone, uuid, uniqueidentifier

I use iphone UUID for checking user's device is unique.

I already know UUID will be changed when reinstall app.

But, I have a question.
Then, when app updated, UUID for my app will be changed?

If UUID changed when app updated, where can I save UUID in iphone permanently(or same effect)?

Answer (score 1):

Save out your created UUID into user preferences for the app, which should be backed up - if they restore the app from a backup you'll get back the UUID.

If you want to be even more sure you can get back the same UUID, save the generated UUID into the keychain - the keychain is kept intact even after you delete an app (not sure if that's guaranteed forever but it is the effect).

Comment: #Kendall, Is UUID getting changed when app has been updated or device OS version has been upgraded?

Comment: The stored keychain, and user preferences would both hang around during an upgrade of the app or iOS.

Answer (score -2):

UDID doesn't change,but it's deprecated.  Device ID might change. One can use MAC address if wifi is on, which is pretty much given.

Comment: UDID is deprecated, not UUID.     https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSUUID_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: Question is about UUID

Comment: That's not what this question is about. The question is about UUID